# Why do one get two different outputs when querying data from firestore database with an async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I guess that I don't get the Google Firestore API for node.js the right way. So I want to ask what's happening in the background for the following two executions, because I get two different results.

First:

```js
async function getDocument(db, path) {
    const cityRef = db.doc(path);
    const doc = await cityRef.get();
    if (!doc.exists) {
      console.log('No such document!');
    } else {
      console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
    }
  }
const aDatabase = admin.firestore();
const aPath = 'path/to/document';
getDocument(aDatabase, aPath);
```

This first code snippet I found in the Firestore documentation. It works as expected. The type of `doc` is DocumentQuerySnapshot. I can access the data of the document as usual. Everything fine. In the console the output is a JSON-Object containing my stored data.

Second:

```js
async function getDocument(db, path) {
    const cityRef = db.doc(path);
    const doc = await cityRef.get();
    if (!doc.exists) {
      console.log('No such document!');
    } else {
      console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
      return doc.data();
    }
  }
const aDatabase = admin.firestore();
const aPath = 'path/to/document';
const docData = getDocument(aDatabase, aPath);
console.log('docData:', docData);
```

This code snippet is only extended by the last two lines. In this case docData isn't a DocumentQuerySnapshot any more. It is a pending Promise. And that is the moment when I get irritated. I can't access the data of the document. I could, if I would do something like `docData.then(...)`. But why is that what the function 'getDocument' returns suddenly a promise.

Comment: `async` functions return Promises. That's the whole point. If you don't `await` the function call, you see the Promise directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async` functions always return promises. To get access to the eventual value, you either need to call `.then` on the promise and specify what code to run once the promise resolves:

```
getDocument(aDatabase, aPath)
  .then(docData) => {
    console.log('docData:', docData);
  })
```

Or put your code in an `async` function and use `await`:

```
async function someFunction() {
  // ...
  const docData = await getDocument(aDatabase, aPath);
  console.log('docData:', docData);
}
```

Note that even in your first example, you had to await a promise:

```
const doc = await cityRef.get();
```

This allows the rest of the async function to wait until the operation is complete before resuming. If you want the code that calls `getDocument` to wait too, then it needs to do an await as well.